# Unable to apply filter(active/inactive) on mat-chips with tick symbol dynamically

Tags: html, typescript, angular-material

I am new to Angular material, and trying to add mat-chips to add the location for my application, and chips should have the behaviour by default ALL location should be selected, and then later user can be able to select one or many location, based on number of chip selected, there is an action.
Now I am stuck how to select multiple chips at the same time with tick symbol on the chip.

Below is what I have tried for this

AddressLocation.html

```
<ng-container>
    <mat-chip-list class="chip-list">
        <mat-chip  selected color="accent">All</mat-chip>
        <mat-chip selected color="accent"
                   *ngFor="let addressLocation of addressLocations">
            {{addressLocation}}
        </mat-chip>

    </mat-chip-list>
</ng-container>
```

AddressLocation.ts

```
export class AddressLocationComponent {
    @Input() addressLocations: string[] = null;
}
```

after I run, it looks like this

```
All Address1 Address2 Address3
```

In form of chips

Expected Behaviour

```
All (tick Symbol)Address1 Address2 (tick symbol)Address3
```

Comment: A [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) demo would be useful.

Comment: @leopal Sorry, I am unable to get the stackbiz up and running, it always gives me error of library/dependency missing.
But if I copy my code to existing running mat-chip example I could see the behaviour of my code.
I am unable to save the changes to post here .
Please let me know if I can provide more information which will be helpful for anyone to answer my query.